# How can I draw those to graphs on the same one and in different colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I just need to put those graphs on the same one, and the points of the first needs to be in different colour than the second one. I think it is something very easy but I can not find it please help. Thank you

```
library(ggfortify)
myPCA <- prcomp(iris[-5])
# drawing PC1 and PC2
autoplot(myPCA)
# drawing PC3 and PC4
myPCAtrunc <- myPCA
myPCAtrunc[[1]] <- myPCAtrunc[[1]][c(3,4,1,2)]
myPCAtrunc[[2]] <- myPCAtrunc[[2]][,c(3,4,1,2)]
colnames(myPCAtrunc[[2]]) <- c("PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4") # fake names
myPCAtrunc[[5]] <- myPCAtrunc[[5]][,c(3,4,1,2)]
colnames(myPCAtrunc[[5]]) <- c("PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4") # fake names
autoplot(myPCAtrunc, xlab = "PC3", ylab="PC4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

```
p1 <- autoplot(myPCA, colour = "red")
p2 <- autoplot(myPCAtrunc, xlab = "PC3", ylab="PC4", colour = "blue")
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]